# elastichsearch search returns no hits but data exist

Tags: elasticsearch

I used the following curl command to list one document.

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:166/qb-*/_search?pretty" -d'{
>   "size": 1,
>   "query": {
>     "match_all": {}
>   }
> }'
{
  "took" : 44,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 6972886,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "qb-ed",
      "_type" : "doc",
      "_id" : "cb7535f4m",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "msg" : {
          "owner" : "xxx@yyy.com",
        },
        "level" : "",
        "elk" : {
          "service_name" : "qb",
          "kafka_topic" : "b"
        },
        "datacenter" : "",
        "uuid" : "0ee56fac-6477274",
        "tags" : [ "hp-quen" ],
        "msg_offset" : null,
        "@timestamp" : "2019-07-16T17:49:48.609Z",
        "host" : "aga1",
        "schema_id" : 1,
        "@version" : "1",
        "dc" : ""
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

But then I tried to search it, got no hits

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:166/qb-*/_search?pretty" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "owner": "xxx@yyy.com"
    }
  }
}'

{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html), which is used to return documents that contain the exact term.

And apart from this, you don't have a field `owner`, instead, you have an `owner` field inside `msg`.

```
"msg" : {
          "owner" : "xxx@yyy.com",
        },
```

So, in order to query for owner, you should use `msg.owner`

If you have not explicitly defined any mapping then you need to add .keyword to the owner field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after owner field).

Modify your search query as

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:166/qb-*/_search?pretty" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "msg.owner.keyword": "xxx@yyy.com"
    }
  }
}'
```